# sql update multiple rows with subselect

Tags: sql, sql-update, subquery

I am trying to copy the corresponding graduation_date values from the graduation_term table into the rows in the user_education_mba_school table that have the matching graduation_term_id.  Here is my nonworking query

```
TABLE DEFS
**user_education_mba_school
  school_id
  graduation_date
  graduation_term_id

**graduation_term
  graduation_term_id
  graduation_year_id
  graduation_date

**graduation_class
  graduation_class_id
  graduation_year_id  

**user
  user_id
  graduation_class_id
```

-- Multi-JOIN not working...

```
UPDATE  u
SET     graduation_class_id = gc.graduation_class_id
FROM    [user] u
JOIN    user_education_mba_school mba
ON      mba.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN    graduation_term gt
ON      mba.graduation_term_id = gt.graduation_term_id
JOIN    graduation_class gc
ON      gt.graduation_year_id = gc.graduation_year_id
```

Comment: Could you please psot the error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several databases support the `update ... from` syntax, which is fairly clear:

```
UPDATE  mba
SET     graduation_date = gt.graduation_date
FROM    user_education_mba_school mba
JOIN    graduation_term gt
ON      gt.graduation_term_id = mba.graduation_term_id
```

If your database doesn't, please clarify which database you are using.

Comment: I think this is working. That's pretty elegant. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Is it possible to join multiple tables here? I have a second table that similarly needs to be updated in this fashion but requires a second join.

Comment: Yes, you can add any number of joins.  But you can only update a single table.

Comment: Oh, I think I need to do JOIN ON and then JOIN ON again?

Comment: Andomar, if you're still free, I posted a non-working version of the 2-join query above.  It's not updating the proper column for some reason.

Comment: In your second query, the `join` only succeeds if the user already has `u.graduation_class_id = gc.graduation_class_id`.  I would not expect the query to do much?  I'd suggest asking a new question, perhaps with a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I just posted the second question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254955/sql-update-multiple-rows-with-multi-join-subselect

Comment: So yes, it won't work because the user won't already have it.  how can i get it to actually force the "correct" one in from the graduation_class_id table?

Comment: What would the process be to find the "correct" row in graduation class?

Comment: Here's a closer example query... posted above.  The schema should be correct along with the current non-working multi-join query.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't going to work because you're setting the entire resultset of the subquery

```
UPDATE user_education_mba_school SET graduation_date = (
  SELECT gt.graduation_date
  FROM user_education_mba_school mba, graduation_term gt
  WHERE gt.graduation_term_id = mba.graduation_term_id
)
```

This should work (untested)

```
UPDATE user_education_mba_school mba SET graduation_date = (
  SELECT gt.graduation_date
  FROM graduation_term gt
  WHERE gt.graduation_term_id = mba.graduation_term_id
)
```

Comment: Does the UPDATE command support aliases? At least it does not in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  mba
SET     graduation_date = gt.graduation_date, mba_graduation_year_id = gt.graduation_year_id
FROM    user_education_mba_school mba
JOIN    [sueldovista].dbo.graduation_term gt
ON      gt.graduation_term_id = mba.graduation_term_id


UPDATE  u
SET     graduation_class_id = gc.graduation_class_id
FROM    [user] u
JOIN    user_education_mba_school mba
ON      mba.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN    [sueldovista].dbo.graduation_term gt
ON      mba.graduation_term_id = gt.graduation_term_id
JOIN    [sueldovista].dbo.graduation_class gc
ON      gt.graduation_year_id = gc.graduation_year_id
WHERE   gc.site_instance_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

ORACLE:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTION a
SET (name, count) = (
  SELECT name, count
  FROM STAGING b
  WHERE a.ID = b.ID);
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of your solution?

Comment: Please, provide an explanation about your answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

if your subquery has multiple rows use IN

```
UPDATE db1
SET
field = 1
WHERE id IN (
SELECT id
FROM db2
LEFT JOIN db3
ON db2.id = db3.id
WHERE db3.id IS NOT NULL
)
```